# I am making a calculator and I wanted to ask how to code the multiplying button

Tags: javascript, html

I've done all the others operations but I seem to have problem with the multiplying option. I am making the calculator using a table and the input type is button.
The form is a table with buttons as rows and columns.
I expect to find out how to get the second variable because I want to use the "for" function to calculate the result.

Comment: Can you show some of the existing code? Especially the structure in which you store the numbers. I am curious why you think `for` is an appropriate function for a multiplication.

Comment: Please add reference code or provide more details.